# Django - referencing different settings files from wsgi depending on server

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, web-deployment

I'm surprised I can't find an existing question related to this. Perhaps there's an obvious answer that I'm overlooking. But, let's say I have my django project named "foo". Settings for foo are defined in multiple files as encouraged by the [Two Scoops](https://django.2scoops.org/) book.

```
settings/
    local.py
    dev.py
    prod.py
```

Dev and prod are separate instances of the same repo both of which are served using Apache through my Webfaction account. For the dev site I want it to use `settings/dev.py` and for the prod site I want it to use `settings/prod.py`. My wsgi.py file contains the following line:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "foo.settings.prod")
```

This is where I get confused. How to load the dev site with `foo.settings.dev` instead?

Could I replace wsgi.py with multiple files, and then in each of my httpd.conf files assign WSGIScriptAlias to the correct wsgi file?

```
wsgi/
    dev.py
    prod.py
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the two scoops book proposes using environment variables to set various settings - one of these should be the location of the django settings module.

So just try setting and environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` equal to "foo.settings.dev" in your development system and "foo.settings.prod" in your production.

The `setdefaul` just sets the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to a default in case you haven't defined it yourself - you may comment it out or just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you @Serafeim for your quick and accurate response. I was already setting environment variables for some information but didn't realize that I could set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE too. Thanks!!

Comment: For some additional info on this, I just found this helpful article: http://bruno.im/2013/may/18/django-stop-writing-settings-files/

Comment: Except that environment variable cannot be easily used under mod_wsgi. Using setdefault() is also prone to problems as explained in http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do it is have each site running in a different mod_wsgi daemon process group. Name these daemon process groups as 'local', 'dev' and 'prod'.

In your WSGI script file you could then use:

```
import mod_wsgi
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'foo.settings.%s' % mod_wsgi.process_group
```

In other words, use the name of the mod_wsgi daemon process group to dynamically select the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Graham for sharing this approach! I've read your comment to @Serafeim's answer, but don't understand why the environment variable cannot be easily used b/c his approach also works for me. Is there a reason why your answer would be preferable? Thx again

Comment: Environment variable are normally set outside of the process being executed in order to override the configuration and my understanding of recipes in 2scoops works on that basis. When using Apache setting environment variables in a context outside of Apache so that Apache uses isn't that simple as startup scripts don't provide you an easy way of doing that on Linux systems.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and the thoroughness of your blog.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton won't this create a dependency on mod_wsgi ? Why will a developer make all this daemon process groups while working on his local system ? While using daemon process, is there any way so that same wsgi file can be used on server as well as local machine. Maybe something like setting environment variable from postscript of virtualenvwrapper, but that won't work for multiple sites.

Comment: Consider putting a try/except around those lines? If the import fails or ``mod_wsgi.process_group`` is not there, you know you aren't actually running under mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the name of the settings that should be picked in the path to your wsgi file. 
Say the path to your wsgi is `/www/production/django_project_name/wsgi.py`, then you could do the following in that file:

```
import os
import re

match = re.match('/www/(\w+)/.+', os.path.realpath(__file__))
environment = match.group(1)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings." + environment)
```